# How to bypass Firebase Hosting's default Vary on Authorisation header

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

According to Firebase Hosting's document: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#when_is_cached_content_served

> Firebase Hosting automatically ensures that an appropriate Vary header is set on your response for common situations. This includes making sure that any session cookie or authorization header that you're using is made part of the cache key, which prevents accidental leaks of content.

Firebase Hosting will automatically put "authorization" header into Vary.

However, some API does need to take the "Authorization" header and determine whether or not it needs to cache the response in Firebase Hosting.

May I know how can we make Firebase Hosting not to Vary on Authorisation header? Thanks.

Comment: please explain your question more. Do you need the authorization header separately or do you want to remove the vary header

Comment: Thanks @UmarHussain. I would like Firebase Hosting not to Vary on "authorization" header. Not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: I think it is put inside response header only by Firebase cloud function, other services don't add this header. So you have to check on your apis other than functions if they are setting a Vary header or not.

Comment: Thanks @UmarHussain. That was what I thought too, until I read the document I referred in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note, I'm a Firebaser that worked on Hosting]

For a Firebase Function that is connected through Firebase Hosting, you cannot change the default `Vary` header that is returned. If the Function adds additional values to the `Vary` header, those will be included, but the defaults cannot be overridden.

[Edit with an idea...]

You *might* (and it’s a big might, I haven’t tried this) be able to call the Function’s endpoint directly rather than through Hosting if you *really* don’t want the `Vary` header to include `Authorization`. You *would* have to deal with CORS and related things, but you’d have more control over it.

Because the benefit of Hosting is that it’s behind a CDN, it needs a good (secure) way to cache the information, and `Authorization` is critical to that. If you want to handle some of that yourself, calling the Function directly may be the best bet.

Comment: Thanks @bkend. I just got the same answer from Bryan Kendall in Slack. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @bkend. 

Regarding your suggestions, yes, it is possible. But as you mentioned, we still want to leverage with CDN. I guess maybe you guys could help to highlight that default Vary parts in document. We only found that line after we monitored the issue in StackDriver.

Much appreciated.